# Get user id and user name from balebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, messenger

Please explain how to get user.id and user.name of client who talking with my bot in balebot. There is a peer class, but i don't know how exactly it works?

Comment: Please post your code here Meysam so we can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a simple way to use get_effective_user() function to get peer_id or accesshash, see:

```
user_peer=update.get_effective_user()
user_id = user_peer.peer_id
```

But if you need more you can get name and other feilds of user from an Update Json. like this :

```
def text_received(bot, update):
        for user in update.users:
            print(user.get_json_object())
            ....
```